# Get category level in parent child table

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb, common-table-expression, mariadb-10.3

I have category table which have category in parent and child relation

For example,

```
| cat_id   | cat_parent_id  |cat_name|
| -------- | -------------- |---------
| 1        |                |Car
| 2        | 1              |Porsche
| 3        | 2              |911
| 4        | 3              |Petrol, SUV >
| 5        | 4              |3.6L >
| 6        | 5              |3606CC H6 GAS SOHC Naturally Aspirated >
| 7        | 6              |2020
| 8        | 6              |2021
| 9        | 6              |2022
```

I need to get all category level from this table.

The need scenario is like this:[image]

Comment: Which MySQL version as MySQL 8 makes it more easy

Comment: Here are some information 

`Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.30`
`PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation`
`PHP version: 7.4.30 `

Comment: None of this is the mysql version. However, you may be using mariadb, not mysql. So, pls clarify!

Comment: I am using mariadb 10.3

Comment: MariaDB 10.3 has [recursive common table expression](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) support.